In libre office calc, I want a function that takes two parameters row, Col, and returns a reference to the cell. Does it exist?
Basically, it's all in the question.
I want to be able to enter a formula like this: =some_func(3,1) and the result will be the value referenced in cell A3 (or C1, don't care if the order is row/col or col/row). I would think this would be easy. But I can't find such a function that does what I want some_func to do.

You're looking for INDIRECT(ADDRESS(row, column)).

Now I want to take two of those and create a range to pass into sum. EDIT - it worked with : between to indirects. Great. Turn you answer into an answer and I'll mark it correct.

"create a range to pass into sum"? Summation range? Then perhaps you need OFFSET()? =SUM(OFFSET(A1;Row_1-1;Column_1-1;Row_2-Row_1+1;Column_2-Column_1+1))

First, use ADDRESS to build the reference string. Then, use INDIRECT to interpret it as a cell reference.
=SUM(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(row1;col1) & ":" & ADDRESS(row2;col2)))

If the columns are letters, then concatenation is all you need. In this example, C1 and C2 contain the start and stop row. This is normally what I use, although it sounds like in your case, columns are numeric, so this wouldn't be enough.
=SUM(INDIRECT("A" & C1 & ":B" & C2))

OFFSET works differently, by specifying height and width. If you have a start and stop, then the size can be calculated by subtraction. Here is JohnSUN's example from the comments.
=SUM(OFFSET(A1;Row_1-1;Column_1-1;Row_2-Row_1+1;Column_2-Column_1+1))

